# How to make image of second slides to be half appeared before it comes out?

Tags: slider, ionic3

I'm using `ion-slides` with a little bit tricky not shown by the default slides but I need to show the second slide (let say only 20% appear before it to be shown on next current slide). However I'm stuck on find the right way. Image below shows my current output:

[image: current output]

and my expected output will be as below:

[image: expected slide output]

---

Below are some of my current codes I've tried so far. You may see the live demo at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-honc8u

lesson.ts

```
page-lesson-list {
    .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
        background: #ffffff;
    }

    .swiper-pagination-bullet {
        background: #c4c4c4;
    }
    .scroll-content
    {
        background-image:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/772803/pexels-photo-772803.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) !important;
        background-size:cover !important;
    }
    .subject-title
    {
        margin-top: -48%;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-shadow: 4px 3px 4px #000;
        color: white;
    }
    .btn-close
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 15px;
        right: 2px;
        z-index: 20;
    }
    .lesson-title
    {
        font-size: 0.7em;
        text-shadow: 4px 3px 4px #000;
        color:white;
    }
    .lesson-type
    {
        margin-top: 57%;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        text-shadow: 4px 3px 4px #000;
        color:white;
    }
    .lesson-desc
    {
        font-size: 0.7em;
        text-shadow: 4px 3px 4px #000;
        color:white;
    }
    .img-logo
    {
        width: 80px !important;
        margin-bottom: -57% !important;
    }
}
```

lesson.scss file:

```
page-lesson-list {
    .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
        background: #ffffff;
    }

    .swiper-pagination-bullet {
        background: #c4c4c4;
    }
    .scroll-content
    {
        background-image:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/772803/pexels-photo-772803.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) !important;
        background-size:cover !important;
    }
    .subject-title
    {
        margin-top: -48%;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-shadow: 4px 3px 4px #000;
        color: white;
    }
    .btn-close
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 15px;
        right: 2px;
        z-index: 20;
    }
    .lesson-title
    {
        font-size: 0.7em;
        text-shadow: 4px 3px 4px #000;
        color:white;
    }
    .lesson-type
    {
        margin-top: 57%;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        text-shadow: 4px 3px 4px #000;
        color:white;
    }
    .lesson-desc
    {
        font-size: 0.7em;
        text-shadow: 4px 3px 4px #000;
        color:white;
    }
    .img-logo
    {
        width: 80px !important;
        margin-bottom: -57% !important;
    }
}
```

lesson.html file:

```
<ion-content no-bounce>
    <div class="btn-close">
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button (click)="goback()" ion-button clear>
                <img [src]="'assets/icon/cross-circular-button.png'" height="32px" width="32px">
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </div>
    <ion-slides slidesPerView="1" pager *ngIf="data_lesson_list" initialSlide="0" spaceBetween="-45">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let lesson of data_lesson_list" (click)="getLessonContent(lesson.lesson_id)">
            <div class="subject-title" [innerHTML]="lesson.subject_title">
                Science
            </div>
            <div class="lesson-title" [innerHTML]="lesson.lesson_title">
                Lesson 1: Scientific Skills
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img class="img-logo" [src]="lesson.img_logo">
            </div>
            <div class="lesson-type" [innerHTML]="lesson.lesson_type">
                Note
            </div>
            <div class="lesson-desc" [innerHTML]="lesson.lesson_desc">
                Start lesson now!
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ion-slide.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-duplicate {
    width: 75% !important;
}
```